# What precisely is gamut in size classes?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, size-classes

When you want to add a variation to an attribute, you get this popup (I'm using Xcode 8) :

[image]

As far as I understand, gamut setting here is for a display type. But I don't understand what it really implies and when I should use it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct it is for display types, specifically, for having content tailored for say, screens with P3 Gamut (wide color) like the iPadPro (and probably the new iPhone)

https://webkit.org/blog-files/color-gamut/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DCI-P3

I think you would mostly use it for images and video, if you have content made for the wide gamut.

I found this, http://asciiwwdc.com/2016/sessions/222 , search for gamut and you can get some of the intent.

Comment: So for now only generation 2 iPad pro have P3 display ?

Comment: I believe that is the case. Will know more on the 12th =)